# Fortify Python Translation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, fortify

Trying to run a Fortify Scan on some python code. For the translation I use the command

```
sourceanalyzer -b Python-Program -python-version 3 -logfile fortify-translate-log.txt  -python-path "C:\Program Files\Python37";"C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts";"C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages";"C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib" C:\Users\sam\development\PythonProject\*.py
```

This command generates logs that have a lot of warning messages like

```
Item 'QMainWindow' not found in package 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' at C:\Users\sam\development\PythonProject\ controller.py:15:18
```

Is there another folder I should include in the -python-path that will remove this error?